# How to do bulk file-editing in common lisp?

Tags: file, common-lisp

I'd like to know how to do bulk-editing of files in common lisp.  I needed this a while back and used perl and bash for it.  I'd like to know the common-lisp solution out of curiousity.

I used the following:

```
find -name '*.lisp' -execdir perl -0777 -pi.bak -e 's/foo/bar/mi' '{}' '+'
```

and it worked like a charm.

The above command feeds all files in a directory (And its subdirectories) into a perl program.  The perl program searches for the regex "foo" and replaces it with the regex "bar", and then saves the new (edited) file in place.

Thanks for any guidance that you can provide on a CL solution.

Comment: The unix command-line is a great way to do it, but if you must use Lisp, check out `mapcar`, `directory`, `with-open-file`, `read-char`, `read-line`, `write-char`, `write-line`, and `replace` in the manual at http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/.

Comment: you might want to use plain words to explain what above line does, don't assume that everybody knows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about starting with [walk-directory](http://weitz.de/cl-fad/#walk-directory), [slurp](http://cybertiggyr.com/sfpc/) the [file](http://www.ymeme.com/slurping-a-file-common-lisp-83.html), [close the file](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/files-and-file-io.html), [replace](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_replac.htm) foo with bar, write the contents back, and then... rest. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `perl` you can use `sbcl --noinform --quit --eval`.

As for the script contents, something like this should work:

```
(progn
  (require :cl-ppcre)

  (let* ((file (nth 4 *posix-argv*))
         (buf (make-array (file-length file)
                          :element-type 'character :adjustable t :fill-pointer t)))
    (setf (fill-pointer buf) (with-open-file (in file)
                               (read-sequence buf in)))
    (princ (ppcre:regex-replace-all "foo" buf "bar"))))
```

Or if you can feed the file line-by-line:

```
(progn
  (require :cl-ppcre)
  (princ (ppcre:regex-replace-all "foo" (read-line) "bar")))
```